# How to transform a list of byte to list of signed short

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I tried something like :

```
    import array
    data = self._data.read(size)
    samples = array.array('h')
    it = iter(data)
    grouped_data = zip(it, it)
    for d in grouped_data:
        samples.append(d[0] | d[1] << 8)

    return samples
```

*data* is a list[] where values are between 0 and 255.

I need to transform so that it becomes a list of signed short.

I tried with an array of signed short type but sometimes it tries to insert values that are "bigger" than signed short because it's not handling the case where the number is supposed to be negative.

Maybe numpy has something that could help here?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `d[0] | d[1] << 8`?

Comment: Taking the 2nd byte as the msb

Comment: By the way, I think `data` is probably a `bytes` here—you get it from calling `read` on something (presumably a file open in binary mode, or a `BytesIO` or something that acts like a file open in binary mode). But that's fine; a `bytes` is a sequence of values from 0 to 255, just like a list of those values.

Comment: `read` is a DBus call that returns a list of values between 0 and 255. not a string byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you almost certainly wanted here is [`frombytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.frombytes):

```
>>> b = b'\1\2\3\4\xff\xff'
>>> a = array.array('h')
>>> a.frombytes(b)
>>> a
array('h', [513, 1027, -1])
```

Or, if that's the wrong endianness?

```
>>> a.byteswap()
>>> a
array('h', [258, 772, -1])
```

---

You *could* fix your bit-twiddling math to do it manually, but why do it the hard way? (If you already know bit-twiddling instinctively because you've been coding in C since you were in kindergarten, then it's not the hard way—but then you wouldn't be asking this question.)<sup>1</sup>

---

However, since you mentioned numpy, you probably don't want to use `array` at all:

```
>>> np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.int16)
array([ 513, 1027,   -1], dtype=int16)
```

This is doing the exact same thing as above, and even the storage ends up byte for byte equivalent, but you now have a numpy array instead of an array array, and a numpy array is a lot more useful.

---

<sub>1. If you're curious, the simplest way to think about it is to just be explicit: To reinterpret an unsigned int as a (2's complement) signed int, you just reinterpret the MSB as signed and leave the other bytes alone. To reinterpret an unsigned byte as a (2's complement) signed byte, you just subtract `0x100` if it's `>=0x80`. So `d[1]-256 if d[1]>128 else d[1]` would do it. Not the shortest or most efficient code, but probably the easiest to understand.</sub>

Comment: `self._data.read(size)` returns a list of values between 0 to 255, not a string byte. I tried using the array.array('h'), but since it's not a byte string it didn't work.

Comment: @MaximeRoussin-Bélanger I have no idea what that `self._data` is. If it’s a binary file or a socket or anything else that acts like that, it returns a `bytes`. But if it returns a list of numbers—that’s fine too. A `bytes` is also just a sequence of numbers from 0 to 255. You can convert back and forth between them with `bytes(lst)` and `list(bs)` if you need the other type for some reason.

Comment: Oh ok! `return np.frombuffer(bytes(data), dtype=np.int16).tolist()` what do you think about that?

Comment: @MaximeRoussin-Bélanger Why do you want to call `tolist` on it at the end? Do you really need it to be a list instead of a numpy array?

Comment: I had to use something like `ast.literal_eval(` in a previous implementation, now that I use the numpy array, yes I can get rid of the tolist.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I can use

```
numpy.int16
```

So I transformed the code to look like :

```
import array
data = self._data.read(size)
samples = []
it = iter(data)
grouped_data = zip(it, it)
for d in grouped_data:
    samples.append(numpy.int16(d[0] | d[1] << 8))

return samples
```

Comment: If you're going to drag in numpy, why wouldn't you just use a numpy array instead of making a list and converting it to an array.array?